# Limit Magnitude divide 2 arcsec

Tags: observational-astronomy, magnitude, image-processing

How can I derive limit magnitude in 5sigma/2arcsec ?

I have the limit magnitude in 5sigma which derive from the magnitude with SNR reach 5.
But I can not understand what the meaning of dividing 2arcsec.

Comment: Do you mean arcsec^2 ?

Comment: No, just 2arcsec. May it means the diameter.